# Upgrading to Typescript 2.0.3 and Angular 2.0.0 caused some import references to not register

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

After upgrading to typescript 2.0.3 and Angular 2.0.0, importing libraries is essentially shooting in the dark using systemjs.

Visual studio refuses to believe the modules exist even though building the TS using gulp-typescript works fine.

Sample import statement in Visual Studio.
[image]

Sample system.js

```
 // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
       ...
        'angular2-modal': '../lib/angular2-modal',
        'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': '../lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
      ...
        'angular2-modal': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index' },
        'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index' },

    };
```

If I build using gulp-typescript though, I get no errors and the modules are successfully loaded in the browser. 
[image]

I even can explore the imported module.

[image]

My tsconfig is below.

```
{ "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "inlineSources": true
    //,"outDir": "client/build/",
    //"outFile": "client/build/all.js",
    //"declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

This has been the issue since upgrading to typescript 2.0.3.

Comment: when you updated angular, did you update the typings.json to what is suggests in the quickstart... as well as running `typings install`? Its okay to delete the typings folder and start fresh as well... also a restart on VS code has helped in the past as well.

Comment: @mrcolombo thanks. Gave that a shot but still getting the error. I cleared out the typings and ran typings install.